# How to choose oldest row from the table of similar rows?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table. Table has structure of id, name, color, product_id.

And the table has multiple rows with the same product_id.

With SQL query from PHP file - I would like to choose only one, the oldest, row. (The first one that was added to the current table).

What query should I use or approach?

Thank you!

Comment: [Edit] the question and add the `CREATE` statement for the table along with `INSERT` statements for some sample data illustrating the problem. Tell us which column determines the order of insertion. And add the query you've tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Just making up a bit of mockup data ... Note the notes I put in. And I trust it's a newer version of MySQL, as the older ones did not support `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` .
Here goes:

```
WITH
-- input ... you *need* a timestamp to identify the oldest ---
indata(id, name, color, product_id,ts) AS (
          SELECT 1,'Arthur','blue' ,42,TIMESTAMP'2021-01-31 17:45:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'Arthur','blue' ,42,TIMESTAMP'2021-01-31 17:50:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'Arthur','blue' ,42,TIMESTAMP'2021-01-31 17:55:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'Arthur','blue' ,42,TIMESTAMP'2021-01-31 18:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'Ford'  ,'red'  ,42,TIMESTAMP'2021-01-31 17:45:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'Ford'  ,'blue', 42,TIMESTAMP'2021-01-31 17:50:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'Ford'  ,'green',42,TIMESTAMP'2021-01-31 17:55:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'Ford'  ,'cyan' ,42,TIMESTAMP'2021-01-31 18:00:00'
)
,
-- select all, plus a rank, on which you will filter outside ..
with_rank AS (
  SELECT
    *
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ts) AS rnk
  FROM indata
)
SELECT
  id
, name
, color
, product_id
, ts
FROM with_rank
WHERE rnk = 1

id|name  |color|product_id|ts
 1|Arthur|blue |42        |2021-01-31 17:45:00
 2|Ford  |red  |42        |2021-01-31 17:45:00
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select min(t2.id)
              from t t2
              where t2.product_id = t.product_id
             );
```

This assumes that `id` is incrementing with each insertion.  If not, you have no way of knowing what the "oldest" row is.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no "oldest" row unless a column contains that information.

Answer (score -2):

SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE product_id = ProductID ORDER BY product_id LIMIT 1;

Comment: Some explanation as to how this solves their problem would help.

Comment: @orhss - this works if you only want the oldest row of *one* given ProductID. It won't work if you want the oldest row *per* product ID - for which you'd have, normally, to use the ROW_NUMBER() OLAP function in an inner SELECT, and then filter by that ROW_NUMBER() result on the outside query. Or, as in Vertica: `LIMIT 1 OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp)` , which is called the _analytic limit clause_ . And your solution would return a random row, not the oldest. Relational tables are not ordered.